# finding a certain class and returning it

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How can I see if an element as a class that consists of only numbers and return its value, ignoring other classes?

`<div class="some_identifier some_other_class 1548"></div>`

So running it on the above `HTML` would return *1548*

Comment: Don't forget that in CSS, "[class names] cannot start with a digit" http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters

Comment: Thanks for the tip, care to offer an alternate solution?

Comment: You could put a letter or underscore before the class name. It doesn't matter too much unless you want to style via it. It's not invalid HTML, it's just that you can't get at it using CSS.

Comment: Okay, that's fine, I don't need to anyway.

Comment: Thought not which is why it was a "don't forget" instead of a mad rant :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('div').attr('class').match(/\b\d+\b/)[0]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rtPa6/

Comment: It would be interesting to see what the difference might be between a regex and iterating through the raw element's classList performance-wise

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
var div = $('<div class="some_identifier some_other_class 1548"></div>');

div.attr('class').match(/\S\d+\S/);
```